# How do I obtain updated props mid-async-function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

This is for an open-source project called [react-share](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share), and their `ShareButton` component has a prop called `beforeOnClick` that you can pass to it. I'm using `beforeOnClick` to upload an image to our CDN so that we don't needlessly upload images that don't get shared, which causes the `url` prop passed to the button to update.

My current problem is, after `beforeOnClick` runs, the share button currently doesn't handle the updated `url` prop.

Basically, I have an async function that looks something like this:

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
  const { url, disabled, beforeOnClick } = this.props;

  // beforeOnClick can cause this.props to change. beforeOnClick can also perform async operations, like making a fetch call
  if (beforeOnClick) {
    await beforeOnClick();

    // call setTimeout to delay the next handleClick call in order to ensure this.props 
    // properly reflects changes from the parent component
    setTimeout(handleClick);
    return;
  }

  // Do stuff with url & disabled
};
```

I dumbed it down for the sake of keeping the question simple, but if you'd like to view the code I currently have, [check out my fork.](https://github.com/Kashuab/react-share/blob/b9ddfe8401ba9012a63acb109b78641dda541b73/src/ShareButton.tsx#L165) compare to [the original](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/blob/61b74adc63f3c015c0bcc9c1a431755f329f2818/src/ShareButton.tsx#L155).

Is `setTimeout` a reliable way to achieve this effect? Or, should I do something like this instead:

```js
this.setState({ __rerender_component: true }, handleClick);
```

I'm not a huge fan of that solution, as I'd have to manage resetting that flag after the callback is run. Any thoughts are appreciated!

EDIT: Using `setTimeout` seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's reliable. If it fails 1/100 times, that sucks.

Comment: So the actual question is: How can I change the `url` prop of a react-share element in its [`beforeOnClick`](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/tree/61b74adc63f3c015c0bcc9c1a431755f329f2818#share-button-props) callback?

Comment: No, because I know how to do that. Call `this.setState({ reactShareUrl: '...' });` inside `beforeOnClick` which re-renders the parent, causing the share button prop to be updated as well. My question is, how can I cleanly and reliably ensure that my next call of `handleClick` happens after the props of the share button have been updated?

Comment: I suggest updating the question to what you actually want to achieve. Add that you've tried `this.setState({ reactShareUrl: '...' })` and why the result is not what you want/expect. Then you've got yourself an good specific question. Your current question is a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I really appreciate your input. Wouldn't this be different, though? I know how to do Y, as I have stated two potential solutions in the question and that my solution works as expected. I'm just asking if Y is a proper solution, and if not, what a better one is.

If I'm still off track here please let me know.

Comment: It depends how you look at it. Yes you solved Y, but there might be better solutions that doesn't involve forking the library. You could leave the question like this and ask it as a new question. Your current solution should always re-trigger the `handleClick` event with the new properties from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest and feels more "reacty" to use setState to have a local copy of the props and let the beforeOnClick function use setState?

eg (beware, I have been using hooks only on my latest projects, so might be off)

```
const handleClick = async () => {   
   this.state = this.props; // can all props be changed?

if (beforeOnClick) {
    await beforeOnClick(this.setState);


 // Do stuff with this.state.url & this.state.disabled };
```

and beforeOnClick can use setState to change the url and others.

instead of giving full control to setState, you might want to have a different approach:

```
 let newState= await beforeOnClick();
 if (newState && newState.url && !newState.url.startsWith("http"))
   throw 'url must start with http'; 
 // that might be a wrong assumption, take it as an example

 // whatever else you want to check, like disable is a boolean...

 this.setState({...state, ...newState});
```

Comment: The child component here isn't using state for this, and for the sake of simplicity of my pull request, refactoring isn't on the table.

I think the approach I might shift to is to return an object inside beforeOnClick which contains the updated props (url, disabled, etc.) and overwrite the local variables.